# jQuery - Appending content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to append the paragraph text into the appropriate pagination link

I.e. 'slide one category' should go into the first pagination and "Slide two category' should go into the second pagination link and so on.

I cant figure out a way to do this properly, in the fiddle example both categories are being appended.

http://jsfiddle.net/gSP47/

```
$('.slider').bxSlider();

$('.slider li:not(.bx-clone) .category').appendTo('.bx-pager div');
```

Does anybody know a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop:

```
$('.slider li:not(.bx-clone) .category').each(function(index) {
    var parent = $('.bx-pager div').eq(index);
    $(this).appendTo(parent);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSP47/1/).